# How to use gitlab-runner metrics?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, prometheus, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed `gitlab-runner` locally together with `Prometheus` - with the hope to discover how much resources does my pipeline need. Both are configured and running correctly.

The metrics I wanted to collect was total RAM memory and disk space of the job running at one time. Pretty basic stuff.

I look at the metrics endpoints that `gitlab-runner` exposes but I don't see - or I don't know how to get to what I want. The list of metrics is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/monitoring/

Furthermore, when I push a job in the pipeline - I don't see most of this metrics move - leaving me to believe this is just the resources that the runner service itself is using - not the pipeline job.